How to get contents of every file (css, js, php, json, txt) in folder tree in text one txt file?
I want to modify some plugins contents according to my custom needs, I'm using an AI language model to do so and feeding it all the data for it to analyze and modify based on my requirements.
I used that method to generate a file tree to feed it to the AI, now I'm looking for a similar way to consolidate all the code that is in each files to one readable txt file.
So for example: If there a file in the tree called "hello.js" and its contents are:
some random js code
And then another file called "hello-style.css" and its contents are:
some random css code
I will get a txt file with the path of each file following the contnets of the code.
Example for the two files I gave:

main-folder > hello.js
some random js code

main-folder > hello-style.css
some random css code

And break down the whole file tree and contents that way.
Thank you everyone for all and any insights.
I tried searching for a solution but only found a solution for generating a file tree, nothing for adding the files contents as well.

Since AI can work with 1 file why you didn't give him all files in zip and AI will do the rest?

@Snuffy Thank you for the comment. That's a valid idea man, but I have a file tree that's pretty large, and I can only attach 5 files at a time with the language model I'm using (Claude 3 Opus), and unfortunately it doesn't take zips.
After your input, I tried gpt4 since it does accept zips, it can read all the files but getting a txt breakdown won't be possible since it'll take too many tokens.

Thanks to @Snuffy I started to think outside the box and ditched the PowerShell approach that I've had in mind. Managed to create a GPT prompt that gave me the exact downloadable TXT file.
